# Insert JavaScript function (as string) into Html and call it

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I want to inject a `JavaScript` function into `DOM` and call it at a later time.

*Something like this*

```
var funcCode = 'function test() { alert("test"); }';

function callFunc(functionName){
    functionName();
}

callFunc('test');
```

How can I do this?

**Update**

*Contextual problem*

I have actions and `function` in the database.
`Functions` are based on actions.
I retrieve both actions and `functions`, and show actions on `UI` but I need to inject the `JS` function for each action shown. If an action is dismissed so the function should be.

`DOM` functions needed

```
var name1 = function () {

    return {
        run : function() {
            // code for action 1                
        }
    }
} 

var name2 = function () {

    return {
        run : function() {
            // code for action 2                
        }
    }
}
...
```

Manager for actions (and want something like this)

```
Manager.Use(funcName) => to call run
```

Comment: in your `callFunc` eval(funcCode)()

Comment: Could you please supply some context as to why you need to inject a function into the DOM?

Comment: I have updated the problem to be more clearly. Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're needing to inject a function as a string into the DOM, and then execute it, you're *probably* doing something wrong.

That said, here's one way you could do it. I can't make a fiddle 'cos they (rightly) don't let you inject `script` tags into the HTML.

```
var funcCode = 'function test() { alert("test"); }';
$('body').append('<script type="text/javascript">'+funcCode+'</script>');

function callFunc(functionName){
    eval(functionName)();
}

callFunc('test');
```

Note - the code above will do what you ask, but I implore you to revisit your deisgn, and look at *why* you're trying to do this. It's *probably* not right.

Comment: I have updated the problem to be more clearly. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
var dynamicCode = "var name1 = function () {return {run: function () {alert('1')}}}; var name2 = function () {return {run: function () {alert(2)}}};";

eval(dynamicCode);

function use (funcName) {
    eval(funcName + "()['run']()");
}

use("name2");
```

Comment: I have updated the problem to be more clearly. Thank you!